# 2 digit month in lubridate as dynamic object

Tags: r, lubridate

I've got a number of dynamic date objects as this type using lubridate:

```
today <- as.Date(Sys.time())
nextmonth <- as.numeric(format(today + months(1), "%m"))
```

Currently, lubridate returns a 1 rather than the needed to digit 01 for that month. I've seen a number of other recommendations that say to use something other than lubridate, however that is not suitable for my uses.

Does anyone how to ensure that lubridate returns a 2 digit number for the month? Thanks

Comment: Why are you converting back to numeric if what you want is a formatted string representation of the number? Also what did you read that said not to use lubridate, and why did it say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does return a 2 digit number for the month, however, you've removed it with the conversion to `numeric`-type. To keep the zero, keep as character (`format` returns a character!).

```r
today <- as.Date(Sys.time()) # Or use lubridate::today()

format(today + months(1), "%m")
as.numeric(format(today + months(1), "%m"))
```

Output:

```r
[1] "01"
[1] 1
```